# The proper way to design a GUI with Qt

Tags: qt

I just started working with Qt, and I'm quite lost with the whole signal-slot system.
I understand the general concept, but I can't understand what is the proper way to design my GUI code.
Is it supposed to be an hierarchy of classes holding pointers to each other? For example, if I have a main window, let's say `W1`, with button, `B1`, that should open another window, `W2`.
It's quite obvious why `W1`'s class should hold a pointer to `B1`, but it seems that I need to hold pointer to `W2`'s class, in order to connect `B1`'s `clicked()` signal to some custom slot of `W2`, and I don't understand why... Isn't the signal-slot mechanism designed to be generic and not specific-instance-wise? What is the proper way of designing this example's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connections are always created between instances of class. Signals and slots are mechanism to inform one instances of class B that there was a change or event in instances of class A.

Below is design of class W1 that will show window W2 when button B1 will be clicked. I skipped initialization of class W1, also getting button B1 because there are few ways to create UI of your window. I added check if connection was successful, just for safety (my habit).

```
class W1 :public QWidget
{
public:
A(QWidget *parent = 0):QWidget(parent)
{
   //init
   B1 = getB1();
   if(!connect(B1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(show_W2())))
       qFatal("%s %i connection failed B1->clicked this->show_W2",__FILE__,__LINE__);
}

public slots:
   void show_W2()
   {
      QWidget *W2 = new Window2(this->parent());
      //create window 
   }
protected:
    QPushButton *B1;
}
```

Here is different approach to your example, where class W1 don't now anything about class W2:

```
class W1 :public QWidget
{
public:
A(QWidget *parent = 0):QWidget(parent)
{
   //init
   B1 = getB1();
   if(!connect(B1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SIGNAL(B1_clicked())))
       qFatal("%s %i connection failed B1->clicked this->B1_clicked",__FILE__,__LINE__);
}

signals:
   B1_clicked()
}

void MainWindow::creatW1()
{
    W1 *_w1 = new W1;
    if(!connect(_w1,SIGNAL(B1_clicked()),this,SLOT(createW2())))
       qFatal("%s %i connection failed _w1->B1_clicked this->show_W2",__FILE__,__LINE__);
}
```

Comment: where i can find how to initialize class of widget properly?

Comment: Do you mean Ui initialization? If you have installed Qt Creator, create Qt GUI project with checked option "Create form", and check the generated code. This is recommended way of initialization in most cases.

Comment: In most cases UI initialization is manual. Even in examples and tutorials of Qt. It's a little stunning. Generated code was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the proper way of designing this example's code?

Create a simple UI with Qt Designer and look at what it generates. That helped me a lot when i was starting with Qt.

Comment: That's exactly what I have done, but how do I create a connection between 2 widgets/classes? The signal-slot editor doesn't recognize other classes slots...